# How to add new counter attribute to xml nodes with C#

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I am looking how to add a new attribute `count` to xml nodes to have it as an id for further parsing.

My XML:

```
<objects>
    <object name="Ford Fuigo" type="Car">
          <properties>
           ...      
           </properties>
    </object>
    <object name="Renault Clio" type="Car">
          <properties>
           ...      
           </properties>
    </object>
    <object name="Evico Star" type="Bus">
          <properties>
           ...      
           </properties>
    </object>
</objects>
```

And I want to have a new attribute like this:

```
<objects>
    <object count ="1" name="Ford Fuigo" type="Car">
          <properties>
           ...      
           </properties>
    </object>
    <object count ="2" name="Renault Clio" type="Car">
          <properties>
           ...      
           </properties>
    </object>
    <object count ="3" name="Evico Star" type="Bus">
          <properties>
           ...      
           </properties>
    </object>
</objects>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create `XmlDocument` based on your XML and then use `SelectSingleNode` to find nodes and change them

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb63z0tw.aspx

you can also use `XElement` like following:

```
XElement root = XElement.Load("input.xml");
int counter = 0;
foreach (var obj in root.Descendants("object"))
{
    obj.Add(new XAttribute("count", ++counter));
}

root.Save("output.xml");
```

Comment: Thanks, but as i had the desired elements inside the xml hierarchy, root.Elements("object") did not work, root.Descendants("object") did the job.